# Hibernate/JPA: ManyToOne to behave as LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of foreign Key

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-one, joincolumn

I have two entity: `Person` and `Email`. The relationship between them is `ManyToOne`. The idea is Every household will have one email - and all the person in a house will share same email.

I also have a case where few households doesn't have email address.

Now when I create a `Person` it fails with `ConstraintViolationException` because at times the email for household is not there.

I have tried `optional=true` and `nullable = true` but it didn't help.

My understanding is `@JoinColumn` is creating a `Foreign Key` relationship. But I actually require a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` so that if the email is null, it is ignored.

How can I achieve it in JPA / Hibernate?

**EDIT**: The DDL is generated by Hibernate. I am using following properties:
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

Comment: Can you share some code snippets? `Person` and `Email` declarations and especially the code that fails with `ConstraintViolationException`

Comment: @SemyonKirekov: I have a controller which creates `Person` using `JpaRepository`. The call to the controller results the exception.
-----------------------------------------------------------------
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [fkhsnjwaek62mr9ejk8986ykrta]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

Comment: that's not self-describing at all. Please, update you answer accordingly

Comment: ConstraintViolationException has nothing to do with the join used and everything to do with the database table creation and possibly your mappings. Since Person will have a foreign key to Email, you must have initially created the tables with a not-null or some uniqueness constraint which prevents inserting your new Person rows without a valid email foreign key. Drop the tables and recreate them in your database.

Comment: @Chris: The DDL is generated by JPA Itself. I am using spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

Comment: That is spring configuration that is 'vendor independent', not JPA. You will have to turn on logging and see what it actually does and the statements it issues - I strongly recommend you clear the database yourself and then let it run, and check what it generates. The ConstraintViolationException itself will tell you what constraint is violated, and the statements creating that constraint might indicate how or why it is getting in there so you can fix it.